# PLSQL Loop through query finds all the records

Tags: oracle, plsql

i'm facing a problem with a stored procedure, the thing is i'm trying to find if the transaction number in the temporary table is already in the final table, if not it will insert the record, if it's in the final table, it's going to a log_error table, here's my SP

```
BEGIN
DECLARE
    date                temporary_table.transfer_date%TYPE;
    auth                temporary_table.auth_code%TYPE;
    transac_num         temporary_table.transaction_number%TYPE;
    card                temporary_table.card_number%TYPE;
    amount              temporary_table.amount%TYPE; 
    num_trx_search      NUMBER;
    counter             NUMBER;
    sid1                NUMBER;
    sid2                NUMBER;
    loopcounter         NUMBER;


BEGIN
cod_error := 0;
warning := 'execution';

    OPEN vocursor FOR
      SELECT transfer_date,
      auth_code,
      transaction_number,
      card_number,
      amount
      FROM temporary_table order by id;

    prfcursor := vocursor;

    OPEN ntxcursor FOR
    SELECT transaction_number FROM final_table  order by id;

    trxcursor := ntxcursor;


    LOOP

        FETCH prfcursor INTO date, auth, transac_num, card, amount;
        EXIT WHEN prfcursor%NOTFOUND;


        FETCH trxcursor INTO num_trx_search;

        dbms_output.Put_line('NumTrx: ' || num_trx);
        begin
          -- i need to check if the transaction number from the temporary table is already in the 
          --final table
          FOR loopcounter IN (Select id from final_table where transaction_number = transac_num)
          LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(loopcounter.sid);

          END LOOP;

          dbms_output.Put_line('num_trx_search: ' || num_trx_search);
          dbms_output.Put_line('counter: ' || counter);

        exception
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        dbms_output.Put_line('No Data found');
       end;  

        EXIT WHEN trxcursor%NOTFOUND;


          --just for testing and debuging
          counter := 1;
          IF(counter > 0) THEN

            --inserts into log error table
          ELSE

                --inserts into final table
            END IF;



    END LOOP;

    dbms_output.Put_line( 'end loop' );

    CLOSE trxcursor;
    CLOSE prfcursor;
    dbms_output.Put_line( 'end cursor' );
END;
```

The thing is, it's getting all the results, for each record in the temporary, should get just one if the transaction number matches.
NumTrx is the transaction number in the temporary table.

I'm a noob in plsql, thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same thing by trying to insert the records from the temporary table into the final table and use the LOG ERRORS INTO clause to push those records that are already in final into another table.

```
INSERT INTO final_table final
SELECT transfer_date,
     auth_code,
     transaction_number,
     card_number,
     amount
FROM temporary_table
LOG ERRORS INTO ERR$_final_table
```

The query above assumes that final_table and temporary_table have the same structure. If they are different you will need to adjust the query slightly. Generally you should try to do as much of what you want in a single SQL rather than writing lots of procedural code to achieve the same thing. It is usually quicker and in this case appears to be much simpler.

For the set up of the ERR$ table I suggest you look at the Oracle docs under DML ERROR LOGGING.

If you do wish to do a row-by-row (slow) update then I would suggest using implicit cursor for loops instead simply for readability. Also I don't think the ORDER BY on each cursor is going to do anything except slow your code down.